# pandas CategoricalDtype: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading the pandas documentation, and by following the first example on [CategoricalIndex - MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#categoricalindex) I've got an error that seems to come from the `CategoricalDtype` class.

Here is the code (the example in the documentation):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(6),'B': list('aabbca')})
>>> df
   A  B
0  0  a
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  b
4  4  c
5  5  a

>>> df['B'] = df['B'].astype(CategoricalDtype(list('cab')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Just to check, I typed in my console the example given in [pandas documentation - pandas.api.types.CategoricalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.api.types.CategoricalDtype.html) but the error persists:

```
>>> t = CategoricalDtype(categories=['b', 'a'], ordered=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories'
>>> pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'], dtype=t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 't' is not defined
```

Could it be that there is a problem with the `CategoricalDtype` class or am I missing something?

Comment: What is your Pandas version? I can't reproduce this issue using Pandas 0.21.0

Comment: @MaxU My bad. I had the version 0.20.1. I didn't realise that this class is a new feature of the version 0.21.0. Updated and all works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work properly in Pandas 0.21+.

For older versions we can do either:

```
In [201]: df['B'].astype('category')
Out[201]:
0    a
1    a
2    b
3    b
4    c
5    a
Name: B, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a, b, c]
```

or:

```
In [202]: pd.Categorical(df['B'], categories=list('cab'))
Out[202]:
[a, a, b, b, c, a]
Categories (3, object): [c, a, b]
```